# VirtualType not created / class not found (after cache clear)

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, virtualtype

Virtual Type XML Declaration:

```
<virtualType name="SliderSlideImageUploader" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">pub/media/tmp/slider/images</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">pub/media/slider/images</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Dependency Injection:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \SliderSlideImageUploader $imageUploader
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
}
```

I have tried \SliderSlideImageUploader and SliderSlideImageUploader for the constructor class.

I have cleared the cache with bin/magento cache:flush, uninstalled and reinstalled the module...

I have deleted all of var/generation.

Result:

```
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Vendor\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide\Image\SliderSlideImageUploader does not exist

Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Vendor\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide\Image\SliderSlideImageUploader does not exist
```

My only idea now is that it is failing because Magento_Catalog is not in my module.xml sequence.

Anyone have any ideas?

This could potentially solve my problem, testing now:
[Receiving object specific class which was injected in constructor by three-part extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154627/receiving-object-specific-class-which-was-injected-in-constructor-by-three-part?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use type to modify the class that was injected.

```
<type name="Vendor\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide\Image\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">SliderSlideImageUploader</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```